# Adding events to CalenderView in Android

Tags: android, events, calendar

I am searching for a solution to add events to the CalenderView since yesterday but i not successful yet .

I have a xml file with the Calender view added to it .

```
<CalendarView
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/chargehis_calenderview"
    android:layout_weight="0.65"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="0dip"/>
```

To the above CalenderView , i wanted to add the events programmatically and onclick on the particular day/date . I should list the event below the calender .

I could add the events to the default Calender but I am stuck in the way to add events to the CalenderView in the .xml file and retrieve in onclick .

Any related answers are advised .

Answer (score 0):

please use below samples which is handling easily adding, delete update event in calender.

https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarProvider.COLOR, Event.COLOR_RED);
values.put(CalendarProvider.DESCRIPTION, "Some Description");
values.put(CalendarProvider.LOCATION, "Some location);
values.put(CalendarProvider.EVENT, "Event name);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.set(startDayYear, startDayMonth, startDayDay, startTimeHour, startTimeMin);
values.put(CalendarProvider.START, cal.getTimeInMillis());
values.put(CalendarProvider.START_DAY, julianDay);
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();

cal.set(endDayYear, endDayMonth, endDayDay, endTimeHour, endTimeMin);
int endDayJulian = Time.getJulianDay(cal.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(tz.getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis())));

values.put(CalendarProvider.END, cal.getTimeInMillis());
values.put(CalendarProvider.END_DAY, endDayJulian);

Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(CalendarProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

I hope It will work.

Comment: Hi , am trying to add the .jar file of ExtendedCalenderView in AndroidStudio and when i add the it to my XML it is throwing some error - "04-09 15:14:46.221: E/AndroidRuntime(5730): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.package.name}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView"

Comment: Are you sure, your given package name is correct in xml file ?

Comment: Yes - com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView

Comment: Its working in eclipse , check your jar file added in your project android studio?

Comment: Ok Let me debug - Thankyou .